# How to make a custom validation in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I have a problem with a custom validation right now...

I have this method:

```
validateInstagram(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const value = control.value;
      let valid = false;

      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }

      let match = value.match(keys.ctrl_instagram_pattern);

      if(match === null || match![0] !== value) valid = false; else valid = true;

      console.log(valid ? { instaValid: true } : null);
      
      return valid ? { instaValid: true } : null;
    }
  }
```

This method validate if an instagram account is valid or not by a regula expression.

How you can see, in the return, if the account is valid, it returns an object, but else, it returns a *null* value.

The problem is that when the string pass the validation, I get this:

[image]

I get *null* and the controller status is *VALID*, but I think it would be backwards, it wouldn't be?

According to this logic, if I put in the return the following:

`return valid ? null : { instaValid: true };`

I get the result that I want.

How can I fix this?

Comment: A Validator function is meant to return an object only when validation fails. So, the current function is actually buggy and should end with the statement  `return valid ? null : { instaValid: false };`

Comment: Aaaaaaahhhhhh Okay... I thought it was the other way around... I thought a validation function returns an object when it is valid... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I use it like that maybe help you:

```
  /* Example form validation custom*/
itemInList(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      if (control.value?.name) {
        const forbidden = this.list.find(itemList => itemList.name === control.value.name);
        return forbidden === undefined ? { notInList: { value: true } } : null;
      } else {
        return { notInList: { value: false } };
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: It helps me too! It follows the same logic as the Olivier comment. Thank you too!